# How get posts from a subcategory of a category by name?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to create a subcategory template of a defined category. 
For example, for each one, I would like to check if his subcategory `Photos` exists and to get posts of this.

Here is my category tree:

```
— Category Sessions
— — Subcategory Session 2015
— — — Subcategory Photos
— — — Subcategory ...
— — — Subcategory Videos
— — Subcategory Session 2014
— — — Subcategory Scores
— — Subcategory Session 2013
— — — Subcategory Photos
— — — Subcategory ...
— — — Subcategory Videos
```

If subcategory `Photos` of **this** session category exists :

My idea is to have a query such as :

`$wp_query = new WP_query(... Session 20XX/Photos ...&showposts=20);`

Is there a way to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a neat, clean way to do it. The following should work, but is untested code - comment if any issues. Wrapping it up in a function would result in cleaner overall code.

```
$cat_args = array(
    'parent'                 => get_cat_ID( $year_cat_name ),
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'DESC',
); 

$categories = get_categories($cat_args); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  if ($category->cat_name == 'Photos'){
    $wp_query = new WP_query(array('cat' => $category->cat_ID));
    // ...
    break;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you anyway @enigma! Good approach

Answer (score 1):

Thank to `@M Haseeb`:

```
// Getting Parent ID
$parent = get_term_by( 'name', 'Session 2015', 'category');

// Checking if SubCategory Exist. 
$term = term_exists('Photos', 'category', $parent->term_id);

//if Exist Do the query
if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
  $query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$term['term_id'] );
}
```

References:

- [`term_exists`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)
- [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: Ah, that's much nicer